# Why are many variable probability distribution described by a Tensor product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Why are many variable probability distribution described by a Tensor product? I am asking this question because i came to know that wavefunction $\psi(x,y)$ is a tensor product of two copies of $\psi(x)$. Can anyone help me understand this? Please refer the following question [When and how did the idea of the tensor product originate in the history quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53039/when-and-how-did-the-idea-of-the-tensor-product-originate-in-the-history-quantum)

Comment: What do you mean by a "variable probability distribution", and why do you think this is related to wavefunctions? Why do you say that $\psi(x, y)$ is "a tensor product of two copies of $\psi(x)$", where did you hear this?

Comment: It is not clear whether you are asking why we use the tensor product to describe combined systems, which is also a duplicate of e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54896/50583, or whether you're asking why a function of two variable $f(x,y)$ is in the tensor product of spaces of functions of a single variable, which would be a pure math question. I've closed this question as a duplicate, please edit your question to clarify if you wanted to ask something different from these two options.